# Xamarin MVVM Cross 3.5 giving namespace name 'Binding' does not exist in the name space Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using 3.2.1 `MVVMCross` in my xamarin ios project which is working correctly. When I installed the same app on IOS 9.2 version Device(iPhone 5), app getting crashed with

> Object reference not   set to an instance.

When I scroll page quickly or when I navigated from one page to other page some times controls (Textfiels, Label, picker, etc...) references are not found. At the same time same code is working correctly on Simulator.

To prevent this I thought of upgrading the `MVVMCross` verion 3.2.1 to 3.5.1, but not able to find reference of `Cirrious`. `MvvmCross`. `Binding`. `BindingContext` and `Cirrious`. `MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.Views` name space.

Based on above summary I have 2 points:

1. Why xamarin `MVVMCross` not able to find controls reference randomly?
2. Whats is the package to add reference of `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext`
   `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.Views` name spaces?

Comment: Have you added the Cirrious.MvvmCross.HotTuna.Binding NuGet?

Comment: i didn't find any package with this name, please let me know whats the package i suppose to add?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Binding/4.0.0-beta8

Comment: I am using 3.5.1 version, can you please provide that link.

Comment: Scratch that for 3.5.1 it is included in the CrossCore package. MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries/3.5.1

Comment: Problem probably is that 3.5.1 is most likely built for iOS classic projects and not iOS unified projects. So you probably need to check out the 3.5.1 branch and build it yourself after upgrading the project to Unified.

Comment: do you have any idea how to make MvvmCross 3.5.1 as Unified ? But my project is classic API project only

Comment: Dunno, it is over a year ago Xamarin told people to upgrade to unified. You are a bit late out. MvvmCross has moved on long since too. I suggest, instead of upgrading to 3.5.1. Grab latest 4.0.0-beta8, it takes a little bit of time to rename all namespaces, to the new changes, but it will save you another upgrade when we hit stable really soon.

Comment: In answer to `Why xamarin MVVMCross not able to find controls reference randomly?` it's to do with Xamarin's linker - try turning linking off and/or adding exceptions (look on Xam's documentation for help on linking and missing controls at runtime... but really with Xam software dev and with Apple iOS rollouts, you do need to keep up - it's the way Apple and Xamarin work... (and Google and MS too!)

Comment: In answer to `Whats is the package to add reference of Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.Views name spaces?` I'd guess you've hit classic API vs Unified API problems. If you update everything to Unified, get all 3.5 packages and clean and rebuild then you can get it working (but chances are that updating to 4 is the better option for the longer term future)

Comment: Thanks for inputs, getting error PluginBootstrapAction class.  i am not able to find reference to Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.Touch.Plugin and Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.Touch.Plugi.                                                 1. public class SqlitePluginBootstrap: MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.PluginLoader, Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.Touch.Plugin>               2.public class ColorPluginBootstrap : MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.PluginLoader, Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.Touch.Plugin>